# How to disable automatic invoice generation in magento?

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am only a beginner in Magento. I need your help to solve this issue.
My Magento store is automatically generating invoice mail  after the payment. The payment is made through PayPal (standard). Also the  order status is changed to 'complete' not 'pending'. So I am not able to generate invoice manually. I need to generate the invoice manually from the admin side ,only after viewing the product orders. The order status should be 'complete' only after the manual invoice generation. Can any one please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also using paypal standard, but I didn't get automatic invoice generation. I am using Sandbox account.If I use Live account, will the automatic invoice generation work?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. Just go to System->Configuration->Sales Emails and under the tab "Invoice" set Enable to NO.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to disable auto invoice invoice programatically then plese follow below steps

1. In your custom module create di.xml file and add preference

```html
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Processor" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Express\Processor"/>
```

2. Create new file at Vendor\Module\Model\Express\ with Processor.php and add below code:

```html
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Express;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface;

class Processor extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Processor
{
    const PAYMENT_METHOD_PAYPAL_EXPRESS = "paypal_express";
    /**
     * Process capture operation
     *
     * @param OrderPaymentInterface $payment
     * @param InvoiceInterface $invoice
     * @return OrderPaymentInterface|Payment
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function capture(OrderPaymentInterface $payment, $invoice)
    {
        if ($payment->getMethodInstance()
            ->getCode() != self::PAYMENT_METHOD_PAYPAL_EXPRESS)
        {
            return $this
                ->captureOperation
                ->capture($payment, $invoice);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Registers capture notification.
     *
     * @param OrderPaymentInterface $payment
     * @param string|float $amount
     * @param bool|int $skipFraudDetection
     * @return OrderPaymentInterface
     */
    public function registerCaptureNotification(OrderPaymentInterface $payment, $amount, $skipFraudDetection = false)
    {
        if ($payment->getMethodInstance()
            ->getCode() != self::PAYMENT_METHOD_PAYPAL_EXPRESS)
        {
            return $this
                ->registerCaptureNotification
                ->registerCaptureNotification($payment, $amount, $skipFraudDetection);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: It's for Magento 2X

Comment: Hi @parth Trivedi I have tried this but its not working in Magento2.4 any idea

Answer (score 0):

Go to Store->Settings->Configuration->Sales->Sales Emails and under the tab "Invoice" set Enable to NO.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score -1):

Use this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/8870.html
I've used in few projects and it works nice.

Comment: this module doesn't work in the last version of Magento.